# Same height images without breaking the resolution

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the same height responsive images inside DIV tag. For example the height can be 200px. Can anyone help me?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Css aspect ratio to have images of same height">
  <!-- include bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="lift">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 ">
       <a class="link-block" href=""> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg"> </a>
       <p class="lift-title">Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 ">
        <a class="link-block" href=""> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi"> </a>
        <p class="lift-title">Text 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 ">
        <a class="link-block" href=""> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/opKg3fyqWt4/hqdefault.jpg"> </a>
        <p class="lift-title">Text 3</p>
    </div>                     
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will get faster responses if all relevant details are included in the question rather than being in links.

Comment: Please do not use external links to show your code since the external links might be broken in the future. I've included your code using the built in snippets for this site. You can click the "Run code snippet" button to see the results. Read here for more information about the snippets: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the width as 100% to `.col-sm-12`

And use the following CSS for the image

```
.img-responsive{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

This could provide the unique height for all the images along with responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to give height of image to be 200px hardcoded and set its width to be auto.

```
img{
     height : 200px;
     width : auto;
}
```

But sometimes it may affect your responsiveness.. May be you should go for `flex`.

Say

```
.flex{
    display:flex;
}
```

Add class `flex` to your `row` this will make all the `cols` of equal height and then you can set the `height` of image to be `200 px` along with `width` to be `auto`. This would maintain the aspect ratio and the resolution of the images and also maintain the responsiveness and you can use it along with the bootstrap classes of `col` as you have used it already.